# How to cover given entries in a matrix with minimum number of rows and columns?

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, matrices, bipartite-matching, vertex-cover

We have a matrix of 0 and 1. We want to cover all the 1's. We can cover a row or a column with a plate. We want to use the minimum number of plates.

Example:
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}

Cover 3rd column and 2nd row. So two plates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $R=\{r_1, \cdots, r_n\}$ be the set of all rows. Let $C=\{c_1, \cdots, c_m\}$ be the set of all columns. If and only if the matrix entry at row $i$ and column $j$ is 1, we connect $r_i$ with $c_j$ with an edge. Now we have a bipartite graph $G=((R,C), V)$, since there is no edge between two rows nor between two columns.

[A vertex cover of $G$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover) corresponds to a set of selected rows and columns such that each matrix entry of 1 is in at least one of selected rows or columns. So, the problem to find minimum number of covering plates is the same as determining the minimum vertex cover for graph $G$.

Thanks to [Kőnig's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C5%91nig%27s_theorem_(graph_theory)#Statement_of_the_theorem), for bipartite graph $G$, the number of edges in a maximum matching equals the number of vertices in a minimum vertex cover. So, the problem is shifted to find a [a maximum-cardinality matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_cardinality_matching)  of $G$.

There are [many efficient algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_cardinality_matching#Algorithms) that finds a maximum-cardinality matching in a bipartite graph, such as [Ford–Fulkerson algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford%E2%80%93Fulkerson_algorithm) and [Hopcroft–Karp algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopcroft%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm). There are many existing implementations of them in various programming languages that can be easily searched.